# Ler vários inteiros em um mesmo input em C

Tags: c, inteiros

Basicamente, eu devo inserir um número que representa a quantidade de inteiros a serem inseridos. Depois, inserir os inteiros em si, separados por espaço, no mesmo input.

Exemplo:

**5

1 2 3 4 5**

Tentei realizar a seguinte repetição, sem muita esperança por saber que havia algo de estranho:

```
i=0;
scanf("%i", &numeros);
long int *vetor = malloc(numeros*sizeof(long int));

while(numeros > 0)
{
    scanf("%i", &vetor[i]);
    i++;
    numeros--;
}
```

Se inserimos o exemplo ali em cima, o vetor não recebe o primeiro inteiro, e o último recebe lixo. Algo como: **[2, 3, 4, 5, -13343256]**

Como eu poderia ler esses inteiros a partir de um mesmo input?

Comment: Poderia postar o código de como você fez o teste?

Comment: Eu descobri o erro debuggando.

Comment: Seu código parece funcionar bem, veja a resposta do Osvaldo. Eu também testei aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long int *vetor = malloc(numeros*sizeof(long int));
    scanf("%i", &vetor[i]);
```

Para leres `long int` nao podes usar `"%i"`.

Ou declaras o teu array como `int *vetor`, ou usas `"%li"` no scanf.

---

Se o problema persistir, deve ser na impressao.
Em C, os indices dos array comecam em `0`.

Um array de 5 elementos tem indice de `0` a `4` (e nao de `1` a `5`).

Comment: Obrigado pela observação, mas ainda não foi esse o problema.

Comment: Também não é isso, pois não imprimo o vetor. Eu debugguei o programa e coloquei watches em todas as posições do vetor. Na primeira passagem da repetição, vetor[0] = 2, sendo que deveria receber 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <conio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
    printf ("digite qtd de numeros\n");
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    int vetor[numero];
    int x, i;

    printf ("digite o numeros\n");

    for (i = 0; i < numero; i++)   /*Este laço faz o scan de cada elemento do vetor*/
    {
       scanf("%d", &vetor[i] );
    }

    printf("\n Concluído");
    getch ();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: uou, leia http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help e [answer]. Respostas só com código resolvem o problema mas não ensinam nada. Explicar o *porquê* valoriza muito mais.

Comment: A única diferença do seu código do meu é que você declarou um vetor estático em tempo de compilação, mas que precisa de um valor inserido pelo usuário. Eu achava que isso poderia gerar erro, ou pelo menos um warning.

Comment: Isso não causa warnings. Nesses casos de exercícios acadêmicos é comum implementar assim. Também é possível implementar dinamicamente. Qualquer uma das formas dará o mesmo resultado.